# Google Sheets DGET() does not find values

Tags: google-sheets

I have a fairly simple table, which looks like the following:
[image: Example Table]

I want to get a specific value from that table. For that I am using two different formulas:

`=iferror(DGET(Bazaar!$A:$K;"Top Sell-Offer";{"Item";"ENCHANTED_COAL"});"?")` ==> returns "?"; Should get some numbers
`=iferror(DGET(Bazaar!$A:$K;"Top Sell-Offer";{"Item";"ENCHANTED_OBSIDIAN"});"?")` ==> returns "2747" as expected

I also tried `=index(filter(Bazaar!$B:$K;Bazaar!$A:$A="ENCHANTED_COAL");;1)`
which does return what I expected, but I can't specify the column I want by header.

Note that both strings for conditions and column headers are copy-pasted and thus character-perfect (As you can also see in the results.)
Also note that **this does not happen with the truncated table provided**, please refer to [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JPP2b6BtwR2uAWZNTmoNE7ZSF9mPagtCT8lGrQCwnZQ/edit?usp=sharing).

[image: Result]

**Why do I get such inconsistent results and what can I do about that?**

Thanks in advance! Stay healthy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a copy of your sheet and messed around with it. Finally, I decided to remove the `IFERROR` part and I got the error of "More than one match found in DGET evaluation.". The error was the key.

The formula is seeing "ENCHANTED_COAL_BLOCK" as another match for "ENCHANTED_COAL". Once I removed "COAL" from coal block, the formula worked as it should.

In order to get it to stop seeing double (to find an exact match), simply add an equal sign in front of the word you are looking for:
`=IFERROR(DGET(Bazaar!$A:$K,"Top Sell-Offer",{"Item";"=ENCHANTED_COAL"}),"?")`

`=IFERROR(DGET(Bazaar!$A:$K,C$3,{$A$3;"="&$A5}),"?")`

I recommend adding the equal sign in front of all words you search for just for consistency purposes.

Reference: https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/exact-match-in-database-functions-in-google-sheets/

Comment: How can you combine the "=" with index output for an exact match?
My problem is that `"="&INDEX(SPLIT($C11; " ~ ");3)` fails as well.
tried also as CONCATENATE("=";INDEX(SPLIT($C11; " ~ ");3)) , same problem